# Rails form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, hide, show

I've a `component` model that `has_many :framework`. 
To associate the frameworks to the components in the form I've write:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :frameworks %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :frameworks, Framework.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}  %>
</div>
```

But now that's giving me:

```
Framework(#70243540172600) expected, got String(#70243531874180)
```

And one more question:

How to hide/show this div with a button? Because the list could be huge.

Answer (score 0):

If Component has_many :frameworks, you can not use collection_select.

In this case form with:

```
<%= f.collection_select :frameworks, Framework.all, :id, :name ... etc... {:multiple => true} %>
```

will return params[:component][:frameworks] = ["3", "4", "55"]. But the component.frameworks - is an association that accepts only Framework objects, but you pass Strings!

You have to use hand made accessor which will accept array of stringified integers (ids of frameworks):

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :framework_ids

  def framework_ids=(ids)
    ids.each do |framework_id|
      frameworks << Framework.find(framework_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Then your form selector have to look like:

```
<%= f.collection_select :framework_ids, Framework.all, :id, :name ... etc... %>
```

What about button... You have to learn [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) stuff.